# Complex objects in Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My React app should be able to display modal dialogs with arbitrary templates. Something like `modals.open(ChildComponent)`. How do I reflect the "ChildComponent" part in the Redux state?

Storing the class/constructor itself is not an option for obvious reasons.

Maintaining a map of keys to classes like `{'templateOne': ChildComponent, 'templateTwo': AnotherChild}` and storing the keys instead also feels ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider storing the Class name only in your store, for example let's say you have a JSON response from a server that tells you which components you need to render in a giving view, the response might be similar to this:

```
{
  "components": [
    { "component": "MyReactComponent1", "title": "Some other params" },
    { "component": "MyReactComponent2", "title": "Some other params" },
    ...more and more
  ]
}
```

You will add that configuration to your state. In your codebase you should also have a component called `MyReactComponent1`, which is basically one of the 100 templates you have. When you need to render any of those component you can do something like this:

```
// import your component catalog
import allComponents from 'my-awesome-package-with-all-my-templates';

// in the render method get the component you need:
render() {
  const { configFromRedux } = this.props;
  const config= configFromRedux[0]; // Get the first configuration
  const Template = allComponents[config.component];

  return (
     <YourModal>
       <Template {...config} />
     </YourModal>
  );
}
```

One of the disadvantages of this approach is that you need to make sure the server returns a valid component's name, maybe by adding those validations to your CMS.

Comment: That's exactly a key to component map. The thing I was trying to avoid as well. But looks like this is the only way if one wants a serializable state. We cannot serialize the component itself anyway, therefore we need a token that would link to it. 

Or just screw the serializability and keep the class reference in the state!

Comment: You definitely need a mapping somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not store the component in Redux state but a Higher Order component

You modal HOC will look like

```
const CustomModal  = ({Component}) => {
   return class App extends React.Component {
       //Have Custom logic here
       render() {
          return <div>{/* The rest of Modal Content */}<Component {...this.props} /></div>
       }
   }
}
```

Now where ever you need the modal , you can use it like

```
const MyModal = CustomModal({Component: ChildComponent});
```

and render it like `<MyModal {...this.props}/>`

Check this documentation on [`Higher Order Components(HOCs)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for more details

Comment: Okay, I have 100 possible templates and any number of modals can be visible at the same time. Are you telling me that I have to create 100 HOCs (CustomModal1, CustomModal2, ...), wrap every one of them in connect(), add each one to the page:
`<CustomModal1/> <CustomModal2/>...` and then render/hide depending on the state?

Comment: No I all I am saying is that you need to Have one HOC, with one template that accepts a custom component to be a part of a template. You can then you this one HOC to create 100 different modals

Comment: No, your example suggests creating 100 MyModals:
`const MyModal1 = CustomModal({Component: ChildComponent1});
const MyModal2 = CustomModal({Component: ChildComponent2});` This is exactly what I am trying to avoid.